# Hibernate - how to remove redundant columns in an assossiation table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two entities: Intersection and Agent.

- An intersection has an **id** and a **set of agents**;
- An agent has a **composite id** compound by the **intersection id** and the **agent id**;

The generated table **intersection_agents** has tree columns: **intersection_id**, **agents_agents_id** and **agents_intersection_id**.
The **intersection_id** and **agents_intersection_id** are redudant. Which is the proper way to remove this redundancy?

**EDIT 1:**

Intersection.java

```
@Entity
public class Intersecion {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMay
    private Set<Agent> agents;

    ...

}
```

Agent.java

```
@Entity
public class Agent {

    @EmbbededId
    private PrimaryKey key;

    @Embeddable
    public static class PrimaryKey {
        String intersectionId;
        Long agentId;
    }

}
```

Comment: It does not seem that you really need intersection_agents table, because that mapping incapsulated in agent id. Provide your entities, plz.

Comment: Edited. OBS: Don't know if it matters, but, the id's aren't autogenerated because is important for the user to recognize intersections and agents just looking at the id (for use on external systems).